# ActiveRecord model not fully instantiating after migration on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, heroku

Getting the following error trying to show a form for a newly instantiate ActiveRecord model.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `title' for 
        #<Project id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>):
```

The method in the controller is simply

```
# GET /projects/new
def new
    @project = Project.new
end
```

---

It looks like the object only has the basic ActiveRecord accessors, but should have title and a number of others. I `pg:psql`'ed into my database and checked the structure and they are there, so the migration looks to have gone through.
The problem is accessing `title` from the form throws the above error.

My migration:

```
class AddTitleBodyToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :projects, :logo_url, :string
        add_column :projects, :title, :string
        add_column :projects, :body, :text
        add_column :projects, :web_url, :string
        add_column :projects, :github_url, :string
        add_column :projects, :appstore_url, :string
        add_column :projects, :playstore_url, :string
    end
end
```

My haml template (which throws the error):

```
.admin-form.work-form
= form_for @project, url: { action: @action, id: @project }, class: 'form-horizontal' do |f|
    .form-group.row
        = f.label :title, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'
        .col-sm-9
            = f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'
    .form-group.row
        = f.label :body, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'
        .col-sm-9
            = f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control'
    .form-group.row
        = f.label :logo_url, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'
        .col-sm-9
            = f.text_field :logo_url, class: 'form-control'
    .form-group.row
        = f.label :web_url, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'
        .col-sm-9
            = f.text_field :web_url, class: 'form-control'
    .form-group.row
        = f.label :github_url, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'
        .col-sm-9
            = f.text_field :github_url, class: 'form-control'
    .form-group.row
        = f.label :appstore_url, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'
        .col-sm-9
            = f.text_field :appstore_url, class: 'form-control'
    .form-group.row
        = f.label :playstore_url, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'
        .col-sm-9
            = f.text_field :playstore_url, class: 'form-control'
    .form-group.row
        .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-9
            = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-default'
```

It all works fine locally, it's only on the heroku instance where it throws the error.

Comment: Did you run the migration on Heroku `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: and then wait a few seconds and/or run `heroku restart` because sometimes the postgres cache needs to be refreshed for the new schema change to be visible to your running dyno

Comment: @Leito Yes a ran the migration, which is why I mentioned that I had checked the Postgres table and that it had the fields I was expecting

Comment: You didn't mentioned the entire column (starting with "heroku") so I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @diego.greyrobot mentioned it was a caching issue and running `heroku restart` (and then waiting a few minutes) seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Once open heroku console and check the model's columns by following command,

```
    heroku run rails c
    Project.first
```

If you don't see title column in the object generated then migrate again and restart heroku

```
    heroku run rake db:migrate
    heroku restart
```

Comment: As I said in the question I have run the migration and I already checked the database table structure